# Stripe metadata empty with Firebase Stripe Extension

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am working on a React app that uses the [Firebase Firestore Stripe extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stripe-firestore-stripe-payments) to allow customers to purchase digital products. I need to be able to update the user in Firestore when they purchase a product so I can make it accessible for them on the website front-end.

To do this I have attempted to pass the needed metadata to the stripe checkout, and I have a Firebase Function setup that successfully reads in the data from the **checkout.session.completed** event.

I can see that the metadata is getting passed successfully to the payment within the Stripe dashboard, and the **charge.succeeded** event, but not to the **checkout.session.completed** event where the metadata field is empty.

Here is my react code to pass the metadata to the checkout session:

```
export const createOneOffCheckoutSession = async (uid) => {
  const docRef = await firestore
    .collection('users')
    .doc(uid)
    .collection("checkout_sessions")
    .add({
      mode: "payment",
      price: "price_1JQQzLJNHX10j3jIUBJezCQo",
      success_url: window.location.origin,
      cancel_url: window.location.origin,
      metadata: {
        'firebaseUID': uid,
      },
    });
  docRef.onSnapshot((snap) => {
    const { error, url } = snap.data();
    if (error) {
      alert(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
    }
    if (url) {
      window.location.assign(url);
    }
  });
}
```

Here is the metadata for the **Payment** within the Stripe dashboard:
[image]

And here is the empty Metadata object in the **Payments** **checkout.session.completed** event:
[image]

Any help regarding what I may be doing wrong or suggestions on how I could achieve this would be greatly appreciated, Thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like whatever code is calling Stripe's API is passing to https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata  instead of https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata

Comment: Looks like that is how that plugin was built : https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/a90ac0ec98a27274f31d101d937e75c9c78bacf2/firestore-stripe-payments/functions/src/index.ts#L200-L202 so you can't really change the behaviour without changing that Firebase extension itself

Comment: Thanks, @karllekko, that makes sense seeing the source code. I might ask the plugin authors about a recommended method to do this. I will also look to find another way to update my firestore users through using their email - available from the checkout.session.completed event.

Comment: Any solution? We have the same question! Upvoted!